# How to merge textures into one in XNA+C#?

Tags: c#, model, xna, textures, xna-4.0

I have a model, that has more then just one texture, and I want to have these textures merged into one texture, so I can use one texture per one model/mesh.

Is there a good algorithm for this? Prefered C#, prefered XNA4.

Thanks in advance:
Péter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though is not easy to implement you can do a model processor that merge the textures into one.

you can use this code to know how do it:

A. To pack the textures:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/sprite_sheet

B. To change your model to use the new texture:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/custom_model_importer

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way would be to do this in your model editor.

Comment: Unfortunately you are correct. I think knowing about [Texture Atlases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_atlas) might help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a pixel shader rather easily if you really wanted to. You would basically need to write a shader which takes in two textures and combines them then draw said shader out to a texture render target. If you're unsure how to do this I suggest you start reading up on shader programming as it's an integral part of 3D graphics programming.

Alternatively you can just use multitexturing and avoid merging texturse: http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series4/Multitexturing.php